# react conditionally render JSX

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here I'm creating a local variable `persons` inside the `App` class then assigning a `JSX` to it based on some condition and then passing it(`{persons}`) inside `render()` method.

```
let persons = null;

if (this.state.showPerson) {
 persons = (
<div>
  <RenderPerson 
    name={this.state.customers[0].name} 
    age={this.state.customers[0].age}  />

  <RenderPerson 
    name={this.state.agents[1].name}
    age={this.state.agents[1].age} />

</div>
 );
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error at `let showPersons = null;`. In VS code if I hover over the red marked line of `let` keyword it says: `[js] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what Carlo suggests in his post. However, you probably don't need the `persons` variable at all. So if you don't need that variable elsewhere in your app, consider the following solution:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPerson: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.showPerson && <div>
        <RenderPerson 
          name={this.state.customers[0].name} 
          age={this.state.customers[0].age}
        />
        <RenderPerson 
          name={this.state.agents[1].name}
          age={this.state.agents[1].age}
        />
      </div>}
    );
  }
}
```

The syntax above is called a *short-circuit evaluation*:

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - `false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.`
> - `true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.`

In your app, this means:

- If `this.state.showPerson` is false, then `false && JSX = false`, which renders nothing.
- If `this.state.showPerson` is true, then `true && JSX = true`, which renders your JSX.

---

Alternatively, you can also use a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

> `condition ? expr1 : expr2`
>
> If `condition` is true, the operator returns the value of `expr1`; otherwise, it returns the value of `expr2`

Which in your app would be:

```
return (
  {this.state.showPerson ? <div>
    <RenderPerson 
      name={this.state.customers[0].name} 
      age={this.state.customers[0].age}
    />
    <RenderPerson 
      name={this.state.agents[1].name}
      age={this.state.agents[1].age}
    />
  </div> : null}
);
```

But I personally prefer the former solution.

Comment: Well, I already tried this approach before with a ternary operator and it just works fine. The idea is not to make the render() look so ugly and intimidating every time you add a new JSX template, rather use a variable or anything that can be referenced inside render().

Comment: @izengod, then perhaps you could use the same exact code, just move it into a function and invoke it inside render()?

Comment: I tried the same code except initiating person variable inside constructor as suggested. but this time this.state.showPerson inside the if() is giving an error(somehow not accessible).

Comment: @izengod you can't use ifs inside the return of render. You must use ternary or short-circuit as I suggested. Otherwise use it before the return.

Comment: great! using the conditional behavior before the return inside render it works like charm :)

Comment: @izengod glad it helped! Please consider marking my answer as the accepted one if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
  let persons = null;
  // ...
}
```

while you should do

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.persons = null;
  }
}
```

See more about the class syntax here https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#classes