# HIde/Remove a component in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React.So i need to know how to hide or remove a component.
I have a Homepage where i have buttons like Logobutton and Menu button.I  click on Menu button it loads a Menu component. I have done it by state. when i click on menu button I  `setState` to true . It goes to Menu component. But when i click on Logo button It still shows the Menu component above the Home component. Logo button is from Header component.So i want to show Menu component only when clicking on menu button and hide or remove component when i move to some other page or click on any other button. How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react conditionally render JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367456/react-conditionally-render-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally render a component based on props:

```
<Component logged={value} />

//value will be the state value

if (logged) //state as prop {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
```

(from https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

or add `style` to a component and conditionally set the display property with ternary operator:

```
<Component logged={value} style={{display: logged ? 'block' : 'none'}}/>
```

Comment: How can i pass the state to another component? Since both a two different comportment

Comment: Check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html. In react you lift state

Comment: i am doing like this in render  {this.state.showComponent ?<MenuComponent/>:null} but still it shows when i click another button

Comment: I can tell if this works because that's not the full code but that's generally the idea